# undefined offset in BoxArray

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to calculate the volume of each box but I keep coming across errors and I don't know how to fix it. Everything seem correct and I followed how the book's example.

This is the error it gave me in this code:

"Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\BoxArray.php on line 16"

```
<?php
$BoxMeasurements = array("sBox" => array("length" => 12, "width" => 10, "depth" => 2.5),
                         "mBox" => array("length" => 30, "width" => 20, "depth" => 4),
                         "lBox" => array("length" => 60, "width" => 40, "depth" => 11.5));

                        $BoxMeasurements = array_slice($BoxMeasurements, 0, 3);
                        echo "The box sizes are:";
                        for($i = 0; $i < count($BoxMeasurements); ++$i)
                        {
                            echo "$BoxMeasurements[$i]";
                        }
?>
```

When I tried doing it the other way I got this error:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\BoxArray.php on line 8"

```
<?php
$sBox = array("length" => 12, "width" => 10, "depth" = 2.5);
$mBox = array("length" => 30, "width" => 20, "depth" = 4);
$lBox = array("length" => 60, "width" => 40, "depth" => 11.5);
$dimension = array($sBox, $mBox, $lBox);

echo "$dimension[0][0]";
?>
```

Is there a special way to call the variable/array name?

Comment: Well the second error is due to the fact that you're using `=` instead of `=>`

Comment: I checked the book and the example it gave me in the textbook is like that and works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$BoxMeasurements` is declared as an associative array, which means you should access its values with the keys you defined in the declaration: `"sBox"`, `"mBox"` and `"lBox"`.

In order to iterate over this kind of arrays you can use the `foreach` form:

```
<?php
$BoxMeasurements = array("sBox" => array("length" => 12, "width" => 10, "depth" => 2.5),
                         "mBox" => array("length" => 30, "width" => 20, "depth" => 4),
                         "lBox" => array("length" => 60, "width" => 40, "depth" => 11.5));

echo "<pre>";
echo "The box sizes are:\n";
foreach($BoxMeasurements as $name => $size)
{
    $volume = $size['length'] * $size['width'] * $size['depth'];
    echo " - $name: $volume\n";
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
The box sizes are:
 - sBox: 300
 - mBox: 2400
 - lBox: 27600
```

Comment: I didn't think about using foreach statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to understand difference between **variable name** and **variable content**, as indicated by using `"` around **names**. It's pointless. It should be

```
echo $BoxMeasurements[$i];
```

While assigning your array, correct syntax is:

```
key => value
```

while some of your "rows" are assigned just "key = value" which throws syntax error.

Also you try to access array by numerical indices, while your array does not use them. Use foreach to iterate the array:

```
foreach( $BoxMeasurements as $key=>$val ) {
  echo $val;
}
```

Finally, you should be doing **post increment** in your `for` loop, not **pre increment**.

I strongly suggest to spend some time and go through some tutorials as you made too many elementary errors.

Comment: You have to put all echo statement within double quotes. I never had an issue and done it before.

Comment: Rubbish. You have to quote **strings** only. Quoting variable names is not technically incorrect. It just makes no sense.

Comment: post/pre incrementing the counter in a for loop makes no difference in the execution.

Comment: Technically, in this case, yes. But logically, you want to increment the counter when you done working on current value, therefore post-incremenet should rather be used, which is my point, especially OP does not really seem to know what he is doing.